# Автобусное расписание

Tags: алгоритм

Интервал движения автобусов по остановке - не реже `T` минут. Существует таблица времени появления пассажиров на остановке.
Как определить (составить алгоритм или написать программу) во сколько должен прийти автобус на остановку, чтобы и суммарное, и наибольшее время ожидания автобуса пассажирами было минимальным?

Comment: Почему бы ему не ездить циклически с интервалом в секунду? Противоречий в условии не вижу...

Comment: ахаха, вы ещё закройте этот вопрос=)

Comment: С электричками проще. Каждый пассажир смотрит расписание заранее, приходит к электричке вовремя. Расписание для автобусов - миф.

Comment: Лол, кто наминусил то?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я уже который год езжу на автобусе, который ходит строго по расписанию

Comment: Ну вы блин даёте! Что, ни разу в жизни не видели расписание движения автобусов?

Comment: Отвечающие и интересующиеся во многом правы в том, что задача некорректная. То ли ошибка, то ли недостаток условий.

1. Автобус не резиновый. Тут понятно, если пришло INT_MAX пассажиров одновременно, врядли они все сядут в автобус и уедут, некоторой части придется ждать следующего.
2. Время погрузки. Это из реальной жизни. Пока все сядут, заплатят за проезд, отправка откладывается. Может сложиться ситуация что отправка будет задерживаться до заполнения автобуса если пассажиры будут пребывать не реже, чем заходить вавтобус.
3. Ну и самое главное, не могут автобусы спауниться за epsilon (+0).

Comment: ЗЫ Предполагаю одной из следующих задач будет задача про самолет на транспортере...

Comment: Интересен сам факт что ответы пишут новоиспеченные юзеры а не завсегдатые... Подгон?

Comment: @Palmervan, видимо из вконтакта приходит народ. расширяют пользовательскую базу, не повредит.

Comment: о вреде ни слова... посмотрим что получится)

Comment: @Типичный программист, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Сами вы завсегдат**ы**й :-Р Конечно, это подгон. Обещанные призы немного смущают, поэтому олдфаги предпочитают помалкивать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итеративно, описываю одну итерацию.

Найти в таблице пики, отсортировать их по убыванию количества людей. Взять, например, 10 пиков. Т.к. второй параметр оптимизации, т.е. наибольшее время ожидания, менее важный, чем первый (метро ночью закрывают, а в час-пик пускают больше поездов), то по нему будем оптимизировать во вторую очередь. Т.е. разрядим эти 10 пиков по длительности, т.е. откинем те, которые стоят слишком близко друг к другу. Останется, скажем, 5 пиков.

Ни них разместим время прихода транспорта.

Будем повторять всю процедуру, пока не упрёмся в физический предел доступный автобусов, или не нарушим законы физики (например, скорость движения автобуса).

Answer (score 1):

Моё решение следующее. Пусть имеется некий интервал времени, измеряемый с приходом первого пассажира, измеряемый с 0. Будем записывать приход пассажиров начинаю именно с этого интервала времени. В итоге мы получим последовательность, возрастающую. Последнее число будет максимальным. Очевидно, чтобы суммарное время было минимальным, то нужно подать как можно больше автобусов за данный промежуток времени. Это можно сделать следующим образом. Находим остаток от деления максимального числа на число T(интервал времени). Именно с этой минуты нужно начать подавать автобусы с периодичностью t.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы и суммарное, и наибольшее время ожидания автобуса пассажирами было минимальным, нужно, чтобы время прибытия автобуса совпадало со временем прибытия последнего пассажира на остановку, согласно таблице. Соответственно, надо подогнать время отправки автобуса так, чтобы он успел добраться до остановки не более, чем за Т минут ко времени прибытия последнего пассажира.

Answer (score 1):

В соответствии с расписанием прихода пассажиров, за каждым пассом приезжает персональный автобус :) Тогда интервал будет не реже любого неотрицательного T и времена ожиданий будут 0 :) Утопия.

Comment: Соглашусь, кол-во автобусов не указано. Да и тип маршрута может быть разный. Ведь есть же кольцевые маршруты...